# How did the CVR of Bashkirian Airlines Flight 2937 keep recording after the collision?

Tags: accidents, cockpit-voice-recorder, tu-154

Black boxes are in the back of the plane.

The CVR microphone is obviously in the front.

When the tailfin of DHL 611 split Bashkirian 2937 into two just ahead of the wing, I would expect the recording to stop straight away.

Yet [here](https://youtu.be/Q8wYhSBmoe8) you can hear the first few seconds after the collision. How?

Comment: The [official report](https://web.archive.org/web/20070123052035/http://www.bfu-web.de/cln_003/nn_53140/EN/Publications/Investigation_20Report/2002/Report__02__AX001-1-2___C3_9Cberlingen__Report%2CtemplateId%3Draw%2Cproperty%3DpublicationFile.pdf/Report_02_AX001-1-2_%C3%9Cberlingen_Report.pdf) says it even recorded for almost 2 min: "The CVR of the TU154M was a four track analogous tape device, which had recorded the last
30 minutes of the accident flight. After the collision, the CVR recorded for a further period of 01:55 minutes."

Comment: Your assertion that the CVR is in the back of the plane must be incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

A CVR has no wireless capability. So clearly the CVR in Flight 2937 was somewhere forward of the location where the plane was split in half.

It is common for the CVR to be placed fairly far aft, but it certainly doesn't have to be.